# Getting error : xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (WolframAlpha)

Tags: xml, python-tesseract, wolframalpha

This code is supposed to get a real-time video stream from my webcam using OpenCV, find text in each frame, create boxes around that text, use tesseract to get text from where there is text, and finally use the wolfram alpha API to get an answer. (eg. if the text is a math problem, then wolfram will give me the result.)

EDIT: This is an old question from when I was new to python, and I figured the answer out the next day. Here's the new code:

The new, working code:

```
import wolframalpha, cv2 as cv, pytesseract, xml, pyttsx3 # imports all needed libraries

speechToTextEngine = pyttsx3.init() # speech to text

exec(open(r'disableVerification.py').read()) # opens script to disable URL verification

wolframAppID = 'MY_WOLFRAM_APPID' # removed real ID
wolframClient = wolframalpha.Client(wolframAppID)
wolframQuestion = ''        # question asked
wolframResponses = ''       # responses from wolfram
wolframAnswer = ''          # final answer to question

cv.namedWindow('OpenCV_Webcam') # new window
camFeed = cv.VideoCapture(0) # our webcam

if camFeed.isOpened():
    running, frame = camFeed.read() # 'frame' is our camera feed
else:
    running = False # main while loop will not run if camera is not on

while running:
    cv.imshow('OpenCV_Webcam', frame) # show our camera feed on the window
    running, frame = camFeed.read()
    key = cv.waitKey(1) # check for keys pressed

    # process the image to make it grayscale for pytesseract
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh1 = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU | cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    rectKernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18))
    dilation = cv.dilate(thresh1, rectKernel, iterations=1)
    countours, heirarchy = cv.findContours(dilation, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # make boxes aroung text and crop so that pytess only sees relevant areas with text
    for cnt in countours:
        xLoc, yLoc, width, height = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
        rect = cv.rectangle(frame, (xLoc, yLoc), (xLoc + width, yLoc + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cropped = frame[yLoc:yLoc + height, xLoc:xLoc + width]

    # get text from cropped image
    wolframQuestion = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped))
    print(wolframQuestion)

    # if c, enter, q, or space is pressed, query wolframapha
    if key==13 or key==99 or key== 32 or key==113:
        try:
            wolframResponses = wolframClient.query(wolframQuestion)
            try:
                wolframAnswer = str(next(wolframResponses.results).text)
            except StopIteration:
                wolframAnswer = 'No Results.'
            print('Answer: ' + wolframAnswer)
            speechToTextEngine.say('Answer: ' + wolframAnswer)
            speechToTextEngine.runAndWait()
        except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError:
            pass
    
    # if escape is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == 27:
        running = False
        break

camFeed.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The full code [EDIT: This is old and erroneous]:

```
import wolframalpha
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

exec(open("disable_urllib_verification.py").read())

wolframAppID = 'MY_WOLFRAM_APPID'
wolframClient = wolframalpha.Client(wolframAppID)
wolframQuestion = ''        # question asked
wolframResponses = ''       # responses from wolfram
wolframAnswer = ''          # final answer to question

cv.namedWindow("OpenCV_Webcam")
camFeed = cv.VideoCapture(0)

if camFeed.isOpened():
    rval, frame = camFeed.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    cv.imshow("OpenCV_Webcam", frame)
    rval, frame = camFeed.read()

    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh1 = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU | cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    rect_kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18))
    dilation = cv.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations=1)
    countours, heirarchy = cv.findContours(dilation, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    
    for cnt in countours:
        x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
        rect = cv.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cropped = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    wolframQuestion = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped))
    print(wolframQuestion)

    wolframResponses = wolframClient.query(wolframQuestion)
    try:
        wolframAnswer = str(next(wolframResponses.results).text)
    except StopIteration:
        wolframAnswer = 'No Results'

    print('Answer - ' + wolframAnswer)

    key = cv.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

camFeed.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aashviktyagi/Documents/WolframGlasses/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    wolframResponses = wolframClient.query(wolframQuestion)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 127, in query
    doc = xmltodict.parse(resp, postprocessor=Document.make)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 325, in parse
    parser.ParseFile(xml_input)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 11, column 0
```

Comment: show us the XML data it's trying to parse. are you using that wolfram library *correctly*?

Comment: show `print(wolframQuestion)`.

Comment: Also, when I remove all the code for opencv and pytesseract, and use the wolfram alpha api by saying 'wolframQuestion = input('Your Question - ')', then it all works, no error

Comment: run your script from a console then. or figure out how to run it inside vscode **and see the output of your script**. that is VITAL.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I hope what I'm saying is understandable - when I run a normal script, then the output of the script (eg. the text I tried to print using '`print()`') is visible in the window.
But when I run this script, the error basically closes the script - so, i can not see the output.
Thanks for your help.